# How to save Bitmap image in Native memory using ByteBuffer and recover it

Tags: android, bytebuffer

I'm getting direct stream from camera and I need to save a `Bitmap` into a `ByteBuffer` and recover it. Here is my code:

```
YuvImage yuv = new YuvImage(data.getExtractImageData(), previewFormat, width, height, null);

    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    yuv.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, width, height), 50, out);

    byte[] bytes = out.toByteArray();

    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

    Bitmap imageResult = RotateImage(image, 4 - rotation);
    imageResult = cropBitmap(imageResult, data.getRect());

    int nBytes = imageResult.getByteCount();
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(nBytes);
    imageResult.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer);

    return buffer.array();
```

Code to convert `byte[]` back to `Bitmap`:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(images.getImage(), 0, images.getImage().length);
```

But then, `bitmap` is Null after conversion...

Any idea on what's wrong?

To clarify: I need to save the `byte[] image` in the Native memory, that's why I do a `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect`. I need to crop the image in a specific point, that's why I need the `bitmap`.

Comment: `byte[] bytes = out.toByteArray();`. Ok. There you have your byte array. On the foolowing line you decode the byte array back to Bitmap. So done. Is that a correct Bitmap? Put it on an imageview to test. `images.getImage()`. So that delivers a byte array? But we cannot see where it comes from. How could we help? And you should have started explaining what is a `YuvImage`.

Comment: A `YuvImage` is the image format that comes directly from camera stream. As I mentioned, I'm getting data directly from camera stream, so maybe I over-supposed that understanding. I appologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[decodeByteArray()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeByteArray(byte[],%20int,%20int)) decodes a compressed image (e.g. a JPEG or PNG) stored in a byte array. However [copyPixelsToBuffer()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#copyPixelsToBuffer(java.nio.Buffer)) copies the contents of a Bitmap into a byte buffer "as is" (i.e. uncompressed), so it can't be decoded by decodeByteArray().

If you don't want to re-encode your bitmap, you can use copyPixelsToBuffer() like you are doing, and change your second code block to use [copyPixelsFromBuffer()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#copyPixelsFromBuffer(java.nio.Buffer)) instead of decodeByteArray().

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(ByteBuffer.wrap(images.getImage()));
```

You'll need to save the width and height. Also make sure the `Bitmap.Config` is the same.

Basically, if you save it compressed then you have to load it compressed, and if you save it uncompressed then you have to load it uncompressed.

Comment: I need to use `Native` memory instead of Dalvik. If I use what you mean, I'm using Dalvik memory instead of native one.

Comment: the second method I suggested in my original answer allows using native memory. I've edited the answer to show more details

Comment: I'm gonna try. I will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

You should also set the byte order when you allocate the buffer because Java is big endian, the buffer is therefore big endian by default, android is little endian and the underlying cpu architecture can vary but is mostly little endian wrt android:

```
buffer.order( ByteOrder.nativeOrder() );
```